# font family inherit from client in Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I have been sending email and always added a few lines of CSS to give the body text a font-family. Removing it I noticed the iPhone mail client and my webmail client shows the mail in their native fonts, but Outlook doesn't.

Is there a way to for this so Outlook doesn't use “times new roman” but the native font and font-size (which is calibre) in my case? Basically the same for all clients.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHPMailer. PHPMailer simply sends whatever you give it, and makes to attempt to change how things look or work in any email client, including Outlook. This is a straight HTML-in-email question.

Comment: Default font for iOS is a version of Helvetica. Default font for Outlook at OS level is Times New Roman. Calibri is just default set for composing emails.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using any `@font-face` declaration in an HTML email, Outlook 2007-2016 will read the declaration but fail to download the font files and use Times New Roman as a fallback, ignoring the usual font stack in the rest of your styles.

There are two proprietary properties that can help you control this behavior: `mso-generic-font-family` and `mso-font-alt`. The former lets you define a font family keyword (`decorative`, `modern`, `roman` — akin to serif,  `script`, `swiss` — akin to sans-serif). `mso-font-alt` lets you declare a specific font name. Here’s a full example of how you should declare your font inside an HTML email:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Calibre';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(…);
    mso-generic-font-family: swiss;
    mso-font-alt: 'Arial';
}
```

Comment: I’m not looking to specify calibre as font but looking to have the font be decided by the client that opens the email. Guess this is done by removing all references to any fonts, which seems to have outlook showing the mail in times new roman instead of something nice?

Comment: @vespino I've seen this happen in the Outlooks on Windows even without declaring `@font-face` in the first place. Sometimes it seems that Outlook is failing to load a non standard font and applies the fallback. In that case, declaring a `@font-face` for Outlook only seems to work.

`<!--[if mso]><style>@font-face {font-family: 'Calibre';font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;mso-generic-font-family: swiss;}</style><![endif]-->`